# Macbook Startup Freeze

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, sleep-wake, performance

I have a mid-2013 Macbook Air (A1466) that has been freezing/hanging during the startup process. It is running Mojave 10.14.2.

This issue first began when I attempted to wake the computer from sleep by opening the lid. Instead of the normal login screen, everything stayed black. I held down the power button to shut everything down, and have been stuck with this freezing issue ever since.

I am usually able to type in my password and have a progress bar appear before it freezes about 1/3 of the way through. Occasionally it freezes immediately on the apple logo, other times it freezes at the login screen before I can type anything in.

I have tried the following solutions with no luck:

1. resetting the PRAM/NVRAM
2. resetting the SMC
3. booting in safe mode - freezes on progress bar
4. Diagnostics test - freezes on progress bar
5. Command-R - it freezes before the utility menu appears
6. Command-Option-R - it freezes before I can select a wifi network

In Verbose mode, it continues to freeze, although at different points. I've included a few pictures [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmbs1.jpg) since I have no idea what any of this stuff means.

Also relevant is that this is not the first time this has happened. I'm now running Mojave, but this issue occurred in High Sierra as well. In the past, I kept trying to login over the course of a few days and eventually was able to log in successfully. That was approximately 6 months ago, and everything was normal up until this latest incident.

I know the battery is due to be replaced soon, though I'm not sure if that's important.

Any insight into what could be causing this would be very appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: how is your RAM doing

Comment: It has 8GB, and as far as I know everything is fine with it...is there a test I should be running to check?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask, when your MBA freezes, how long do you normally leave it to see what happens? I'm particularly interested in those times you're trying to boot into Recovery. Also, do you have access to any other Macs? If so, which models? Finally, when you say you've tried a *Diagnostics test*, can you elaborate? Were you using **CMD+D** on startup or some other software?

Comment: Thank you! The first 10 times or so I waited for about an hour each time. I've also waited overnight a few times. This is for both recovery and normal boot. Unfortunately, I don't have access to any other macs For the diagnostics, I was using the cmd-d as you stated

Comment: first get rid of the lock screen banner

Comment: Thank you for helping! I'm trying to figure out how I can avoid loading the lock screen banner without working from system preferences...still working on that haha

Answer (score 1):

> This issue first began when I attempted to wake the computer from
>   sleep by opening the lid. Instead of the normal login screen,
>   everything stayed black.

The Black screen was caused by this error.

[image]

It tried to load your Screen lock .png but failed to do so.

Remove Screen lock settings, reboot and see if it works. Reset Screen lock with new message.

Since the Screen lock settings resides in NVRAM it will remain unchanged even if you upgrade to new OSX or Reset NVRAM.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will give this a shot as soon as possible.